# как поменять тему в sublime text 3 полностью?

Tags: текст, sublime-text

Помогите изменить саму тему sublime как на первой картинке а то классическая уже порядком поднадоела

[image: вот результат который хотелось бы получить]

[image: а вот то что сейчас]

Answer (score 1):

Нажимаете в меню Preferences -> Package Control. Ищете там пункт Package Control: Install Package. Нажимаете на него. Откроется окно со списком доступных пакетов.

Я не уверен но ваш скриншот похож на Material Theme. Можно в поле ввода написать Material Theme, потом нажать на него в списке. Тема начнёт устанавливаться.
В процессе может попросить установить ещё пакет, надо согласиться (нажать Install).

После того как пакет установится нужно будет активировать его. Preferences -> Package Settings -> Material Theme -> Activate. Будет выбор из четырёх цветовых решений для данной темы. Выбираете и пользуетесь.