# как сделать темную тему в sublime text 3?

Tags: sublime-text-3, themes, sublime-text-4

я лазил в настройках sublime text и он решил как то переключится с темной темы на светлую,глаза режет,помогите(не шрифт,а фон)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и я искал насчет этого и на стеке, и в гугле,ничего не нашел если че

Comment: На этот и другие вопросы  по настройке sublime text есть много хороших статей в интернете... Так же за пару секунд нашел похожий вопрос на [Stack Overflow ][1] [1]: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1201896/467311

Comment: `Preferences>Color Scheme`

Comment: С чем именно вам помочь?  Переключить тему обратно на темную?  Отрегулировать яркость монитора?  Выслать дымчатые очки?

Comment: это изменение шрифта,там тема фона белая как бы

Comment: да,переключить тему обратно на темную

Comment: блин,извиняюсь,протупил, от души Кирилл